# Identify a new inserted record from a record obtained by query

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

How can I identify in oracle forms the difference between a record obtained from the database and one just newly inserted ?
I need to requery after a button click if the record is queried before and if it is a newly inserted record then I only need to query the new record, because a requery won't contain the new record or if no query happened before then a requery will do a full query.

I tried with `:system.record_status`, but after commit it also contains `QUERY`

Answer (score 0):

Exactly; after commit & requery, all records are *equal* and their status is QUERY.

I don't think you can do that, unless you *mark* newly added rows, somehow (e.g. by adding a timestamp so all rows with the `MAX(timestamp)` value are considered to be new).

Comment: I assumed something like that, it would have been better to use system variables

Comment: It would, I agree, but - how? Its previous value is now lost.